# How do I know if a power supply will work with my monitor?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, monitor

I've got a monitor which takes 19V 2A (AOC I2381FH) that I've lost the power supply to. I've got a power supply which will fit which says it produces 12V 2.5A which sounds like it might work.

Would I likely damage my monitor by using this? Trying to find a replacement supply seems difficult for it.

Comment: It most likely won't work. Was the original power supply *external* to the monitor ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Answer (score 1):

Check the info label on your monitor to view the acceptable input voltages.

My guess is that it won't work as 12V won't be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need a 19V, 2A power supply. The required power is 38W, the 12V 2.5A can only supply 30W.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way of knowing what kind of connector will fit in it?

Comment: If you have to buy someting anyway, why buy random power supplies if you are unable to determine if they are suitable or not. Why not buy a replacement power supply from the monitor manufacturer, so you know that it's compatible.

Comment: They don't seem to sell them unfortunately, at least not in the UK

Comment: 19V is (or used to be) a standard laptop charging voltage - I have several old chargers with that output. You should be able to find a universal charger on Fleabay or similar. It is also likely that your monitor has a standard tubular connector, but you need to check.

Comment: I bought one but it doesn't fit sadly. I have no idea how to really check if it fits properly or not :/ sadly it's not like usb where it's relatively standardised haha

Comment: @JoeSimpson:  Barrel connectors are somewhat standardized.  You need to measure the diameter of the center pin and the diameter of the hole for the barrel.  Use a caliper.